# Why do we need a consistency assumption in causal inference?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, inference, causality

Why do we need a consistency assumption in causal inference? I think the consistency assumption is quite obvious and it is more like a definition for the observed outcome.

[image]

Comment: Please mind your spelling, thank you.

Comment: Please include a reference for the image as presumably this is someone else's work. (Also, it's best to avoid posting images altogether.)

Comment: @dipetkov, images are certainly helpful in many cases. What you probably meant is that it is better to post text as text instead of text as image.

Comment: @RichardHardy Yes. Comment is in brackets because I think it's even more important to include the source (of image, text or data).

Answer (score 7):

In one [article](https://www.nature.com/articles/ijo200882), Hernán indeed writes

> "Consistency may seem so obvious as to hardly deserve any attention. As a consequence, the condition of consistency is
> often taken for granted [...]"

Then, he goes on to demonstrate why it's not so simple.

Problems can in particular arise in observational studies, where the "treatment" $A$, e.g., gender, might not be unambiguously linked to an intervention. It is then hard to conceive what is meant by a statement like "had the person been assigned to the other gender", i.e., by an expression like

$$
Y_{A=0}|A = 1.
$$

What is the interveining assignment mechanism of gender here that we are interested in? Is a change in name enough? (If we are looking at hiring discrimination from CVs, that might actually be enough) Or do we need to think of a person with all the same personality charachteristics, but different biological sex? Or a person born to the other sex and raised accordingly, including all socially learned gender roles? The same ambiguity makes it unclear what in this case we even mean by

$$
Y_{A=0}|A = 0.
$$

There is no well-defined invervention $A$, and hence no well-defined causal contrast. Practically, this has downstream problems for data analysis, like the selection of adjustment variables. It is also linked to problems in evaluating the positivity assumption (see the article).

In short, evaluating the consistency assumption guides us towards well-defined causal questions.

Edit: See also the way more elaborate response [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/304799/in-causal-inference-in-statistics-how-do-you-interpret-the-consistency-assumpti?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

### Variable relationships in causal models are generally stochastic

A reason why the fact that the link between assignment and observed outcome of the intervention is consistent may be noteworthy is because in causal models the relationships between variables are generally thought to be stochastic.

Without the assumption it may well be conceivable that, although $A=1$ is assigned, we observe the result for $A=0$, similarly to how it is often assumed that there is an independent error term associated with the outcome. This could be because the assignment didn't work or was changed by a factor outside of our control (see the other answer for an example).